# Unable to Join two database tables cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp-3.0

i am using multiple two database with name 'default' and 'default_history. Under 'default' db i have table with name 'recipes', and 'order_detail_history' under 'default_history' db. I have model table with name OrderDetailHistoryTable. here my model table :-

```
public static function defaultConnectionName()  
{
    return 'default_history';
}

public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->setTable('order_detail_history');
    $this->setDisplayField('id');
    $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

    $this->belongsTo('RecipesLeft', [
        'strategy' => 'select',
        'propertyName' => 'Recipes',
        'className' => 'Recipes',
        'foreignKey' => 'recipe_id',
        'joinType' => 'LEFT'
    ]);
}
```

i am using query:-

```
$recipe_list_history = $this->OrderDetailHistory->find('list', ['keyField' => 'RecipesLeft.id', 'valueField' => 'RecipesLeft.recipe_name'])->select(['RecipesLeft.id', 'RecipesLeft.recipe_name'])->contain(['RecipesLeft'])->where(['OrderDetailHistory.order_id' => $history_id])->order(['OrderDetailHistory.id'])->hydrate(false)->toArray();
```

and i am getting this db error:-

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'RecipesLeft.id' in 'field list'
SELECT RecipesLeft.id AS `RecipesLeft__id`, RecipesLeft.recipe_name AS `RecipesLeft__recipe_name` FROM order_detail_history OrderDetailHistory WHERE OrderDetailHistory.order_id = :c0 ORDER BY OrderDetailHistory.id
```

i have define association in model table, but i am unable to join recipes table with order_detials_history.!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Recipes table does not have an id column (primary key). Can you post your database scheme of the three tables!

Comment: Recipes include id column. recipes is from default database and order_details is from default_history database.